# Build m4, autoconf, automake, libtool on unix

Tags: unix, autoconf, automake, m4

I'm trying to setup PHP, apache environment on HP-UX server. While install i'm using usual commands of "./configur, make, make install". Here when I'm trying to install PCRE I got an error like follows.

```
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/softwares/m4-1.4.17/build-aux/missing aclocal-1.14 -I m4 /home/ubuntu/softwares/m4-1.4.17/build-aux/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.14: command not found WARNING: 'aclocal-1.14' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/> Makefile:1496: recipe for target 'aclocal.m4' failed make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

So I download latest versions of "m4, autoconf and automake" source and try to install using usual make command.

First I tried to install "automake" it through error asking to install "autoconf"
Then I tried to install autoconf again it ask to install "m4"
Then I tried to install "m4" now it through the same error above listed.
So it became a loop of same set of error not letting me to install.

Can any one help me to sort this issues. Please consider this is a HP-UX unix server so don't recommend the famous ubuntu "apt-get install" command or red hat specific commands.

Comment: You do not need to install the autotools.  Most likely, the problem is caused by a timestamp skew and some files in the pcre tarball have been unpacked with incorrect timestamps.  (This often happens if you unpack the tarball on a network drive.)  Trying to recreate the configure script using the autotools is not the simplest solution.

Comment: Great comment William. I did a recursive touch on my files and the problem disappeared.  Indeed, the problem appeared in the first place because of file transfers from another machines. I voted up Jason's answer, but it was your clues that did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First read William Pursell's comment to your post (above).  If you still need to install the autotools ...

1. Check to see what, if any, autotools you may already have installed by typing: `m4 --version`and `autoconf --version`and `automake --version`.
2. You should use HP-UX's package manager. It's called Software Distributor (SD). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Distributor
3. HP-UX's FAQ 5.9 explains how to handle dependencies using depothelper. http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/answers/5-9.html
4. Here is where you find the correct autotool packages (autoconf, automake, libtool) for HP-UX.  Install these HP-UX packages using HP-UX's native package manager instead of compiling from source. http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/packages.html

Comment: He is on HP-UX. No RPM there.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with m4.  In my case, *the problem was I was transferring all the source files via `scp` to a server.*

When I tried to `configure`, `make` and `make install` through `ssh`, this kept happening.  **I believe something did not transfer the way it was supposed to.**

> The problem was solved by manually transferring the files
>   through a USB.

It's not a perfect solution (it implies physical access to the server) but it works.