# Installing autotools on MinGW - stuck in a loop

Tags: mingw, autoconf, automake, mingw-w64, m4

I'm trying to install autotools for a while now and without success. I need automake to install a package (xraylib).

## Problem:

While trying to install automake, it tells me I need autoconfig to install it:
`configure: error: Autoconf 2.65 or better is required.
    Please make sure it is installed and in your PATH.`

So then I tried to install autoconfig v.2.65 and it tells me I need to install M4 before:
`checking for GNU M4 that supports accurate traces... configure: error: no acceptable m4 could be found in $PATH.
GNU M4 1.4.6 or later is required; 1.4.13 is recommended`

So finally I went for M4 v.1.4.9
It runs ./configure completely with no errors. I don't know if it takes the `make` command to complete the installation, since when I go back to autoconfig, the same error appears when running ./configure

I've been running around in circles for hours now.
Ticket [Build m4, autoconf, automake, libtool on unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233721) didn't help.

## Considerations:

System OS: Windows 10 Pro
Using Git-Bash (mintyy 3.0.1)

I'm installing all packages under `user\bin\`
I tried adding m4 to PATH. (C:\Users\user\bin\m4-1.4.9)

Comment: MinGW-w64 isn't an environment. Do you mean you're using Windows Command Prompt with mingw-w64 environment variables set?

Comment: I installed MinGW 64 and am using it to run stuff, not via the cmd itself. But idk if cmd is running in the background if that was the question. 
idk the technical terms for each thing, but in sum I'm using git bash terminal version is Mintyy 3.0.1

Comment: Maybe autotools don't work in Git Bash.  If you can't find a solution for Git Bash then one option is to install MSYS2 instead (which has a package manager from which you can install mingw-w64, git and autotools).

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it qith [MINGW64 "make build" error: "bash: make: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770716)

with [Vallabha Vamaravelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420343/vallabha-vamaravelli)  answer below:

> - Go to ezwinports, https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/
> - Download make-4.2.1-without-guile-w32-bin.zip (get the version without guile)
> - Extract zip
> - Copy the contents to C:\ProgramFiles\Git\mingw64\ merging the folders, but do NOT > overwrite/replace any exisiting files.